# How to avoid braces in \usepackage generated with pylatex for package names containing "-"?

Tags: python, pylatex

I need to create a LaTeX document with the package "tikz-feynman" in Python.

I use pylatex but, when I try to create the file like this

```py
doc = Document("my_diagram")
doc.packages.append((Package("tikz-feynman", options=["compat = 1.0.0"])))
doc.append("Some text...")
doc.generate_tex()
```

it can't compile. This is because of a pair of braces in the name of the package tikz-feynman. When I run the code the .tex file has the header

```latex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[compat = 1.0.0]{tikz{-}feynman}%
```

instead of

```latex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[compat = 1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}%
```

How can I avoid those braces from occuring?

Comment: What happens if you use `Package("{tikz-feynman}", ...)`?

Comment: the result becomes `\usepackage[compat = 1.0.0]{\{tikz{-}feynman\}}%` so the problem remains..

Comment: Okay, that was just a guess. And what is the error message when trying to compile the document with `tikz{-}feynman`? Maybe that is correct after all.

Comment: Actually there is no error message. But when i compile the .tex without the braces it takes ~ 3.5 seconds, and with, even over 10 minutes it still compiling

Answer (score 0):

I've find a solution ! We can simple replace the line

```py
doc.packages.append((Package("tikz-feynman", options=["compat = 1.0.0"])))
```

by

```py
doc.preamble.append(NoEscape(r"\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}"))
```